# Trying to load a jpg onto a page based on a URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a site page (Wiki Page) that is re-used based on the URL Parameter that is sent when opening the page.  The URL Parameter is used to filter out the contents of various document libraries and custom list on the page.

In addition, I would like to add code that will take this URL Parameter and lookup an item in a custom list to get a JPG image and replace the image that is currently on the page.  (Or insert it in the upper left section of the page).

Any idea as to how I can accomplish this?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried that is not working (my guess is nothing and you just want someone to think for you)? There are so many ways to do this they are practically uncountable. You have given us nothing to work with at all. Nothing about server tech. I'm really confused by the `sharepoint-2013` tag. What does that have to do with it? And I have no idea how you think this has anything to to do with javascript.

Comment: Wiki page is a page type in SharePoint 2013.  So the tag is very applicable. If you read the description, there are libraries and custom lists in the description.  I have no clue how to do this.  I'm not an expert in how this would be done.  I can do some JavaScript and jquery and I can get data from a custom list, but have no clue how I would do this.  Why is asking how to do something worth getting negative points.

Comment: "Why is asking how to do something worth getting negative points." Because this is a site about specific programming problems and it's expected that those problems can be demonstrated with **code**.  Read this: [ask] and this [mre].  It's not that what you want to know is "bad". It's just that what you're asking and how you're asking it is not appropriate for this site. Posts are useful the more they can be of use to a wide range of users. If I asked on an automotive site: "My car won't start. What's wrong?" and that's all I said, How would they be able to help me? Now reread your post.

Comment: If you read your references, what I am asking for is ok.  What you are doing is bad.  Here I will repeat the exact wording, "The guidelines outlined below are rooted in two principles:

It is okay to ask about homework. For one, it would be impossible to stop it all even if we wanted to. Stack Overflow exists to help programmers learn and provide a standard repository for programming problems, both simple and complex, and this includes helping students."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this site is now punishing students/users learning by rating homework questions as negative, I will rise above the "expert" users and post an answer to this homework.  It took me a lot of time, because this is not my expertise.

I created a Script Editor web part with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/js-enterprise/DisplayVirtualPicture.CEWP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', LoadAll);
        function LoadAll()
        {getPicture();}
</script>
<img style="max-width:600px" title="undefined" src="https:xxxxxxx/SiteAssets/images/Blank.jpg">
```

The script **DisplayVirtualPicture.CEWP.js** is:

```
var currentID = GetUrlKeyValue('Name');
//console.log(currentID);

function getPicture() {
    var mytable = "";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('VirtualPageLibrary');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>'+ currentID +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 

    var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    //clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(VirtualPicture, Title, Id)');
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
       var swListItms = collListItem.getEnumerator();
       while (swListItms.moveNext())
       {
           var swItm = swListItms.get_current();
           var mytable = swItm.get_item('VirtualPicture').get_url(); 
           //console.log("img="+mytable);
           $("img[title='undefined']").attr("src",mytable);
       }
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceededp,onQueryFailedp);
    },
    function (sender, args) 
    {
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
}

function onQuerySucceededp(sender, args) {
    //console.log("success-1");
}
function onQueryFailedp(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

It may not be the most efficient way of accomplishing this, but without the cooperation with expert users on this site, it's the best I can do.